# Wrapping nested <div> with incrementing ids around elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just learning jQuery and came across a problem that stumped me. I need to move, add & name divs with out affecting the content.

I have a single fixed width WRAPPER div with SECTION divs inside. This is what it looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="whitewrap">

    <div id="wrapper-1" class="wrapper">
        <div class="clearfix">

            <section id="block-1">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Some wonderful content.</p>
            </section><!-- #block-1 -->

            <section id="block-2">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Some wonderful content.</p>
            </section><!-- #block-2 -->

            <section id="block-3">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Some wonderful content.</p>
            </section><!-- #block-3 -->

        </div><!-- .clearfix -->
    </div><!-- #wrapper-1 -->

</div><!-- #whitewrap -->
</body>
```

What I need is each SECTION to have it's own WRAPPER div plus add a CONTAINER div around each wrapper. The ID # for WRAPPERS and CONTAINERS need to auto increase because the SECTIONS are dynamically added.

This is what I imagine.

```
<body>
<div id="whitewrap">

    <div id="container-1">
        <div id="wrapper-1" class="wrapper">
            <div class="clearfix">

            <section id="block-1">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Some wonderful content.</p>
            </section><!-- #block-1 -->

            </div><!-- .clearfix -->
        </div><!-- #wrapper-1 -->
    </div><!--#container-1 -->

    <div id="container-2">
        <div id="wrapper-2" class="wrapper">
            <div class="clearfix">

            <section id="block-2">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Some wonderful content.</p>
            </section><!-- #block-2 -->

            </div><!-- .clearfix -->
        </div><!-- #wrapper-2 -->
    </div><!--#container-2 -->

    <div id="container-3">
        <div id="wrapper-3" class="wrapper">
            <div class="clearfix">

            <section id="block-3">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Some wonderful content.</p>
            </section><!-- #block-3 -->

            </div><!-- .clearfix -->
        </div><!-- #wrapper-3 -->
    </div><!--#container-3 -->

</div><!-- #whitewrap -->
</body>
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you have any javascript to show what you've tried?

Comment: Agree with @travis. Here's the relevant section of documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap)/[`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap) is what you're looking for here. Specifically, the overload that supplies you an index parameter will be helpful:

```
$("#block-1").unwrap().unwrap();

$("section").wrap(function(i) {
    var num = i + 1;

    return "<div id='container-" + num + "'>" + 
        "<div id='wrapper-" + num + "' class='wrapper'>" + 
        "<div class='clearfix'></div></div></div>";
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/NfuGz/1/

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery's [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function with an incrementing counter.  Pass a function to `.wrap()` which builds an HTML snippet to surround each `<section>`, using the counter as needed in ids and incrementing it:

```
var counter = 1;
$('section').wrap(function() {
  // Make a string of the HTML which should wrap around each <section>
  var wrapper = '<div id="container-' + counter + '"><div id="wrapper-' + counter + '" class="wrapper"></div></div>';
  // Increment the counter
  counter++;
  // Return the string and it will be applied around each <section>
  return wrapper;
});
```

[Here's a demo...](http://jsfiddle.net/QApF8/1/)

Note: You already have a `<div id="wrapper-1" />` surrounding the whole thing. If that should be removed (which it ought to if you have another `wrapper-1` around a `<section>`), use [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) first:

```
$("div.clearfix").unwrap();
// Then run the rest of the code...
```

[As in this demo...](http://jsfiddle.net/QApF8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/). To auto increment the number you can use the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) on [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `section`.

In any case, I would consider rethinking the tags tree, I'm not sure if `section` wrapped in many `div`s is the most semantically correct thing to do. Maybe `article` fits better? Quoting from the [**w3**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/sections.html#the-section-element) site:

> *The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.*

Comment: You're right but his is more of a "Research your own solution kind of answer" for a "What have you tried kind of question"...